# Creating realistic latex "face masks" from fotography

Tags: technology, dermatology

In many action movies (especially in Mission Impossible, Fantomas but in many others too) are created latex masks that very closely and realistically resemble the face of someone else.

In the real world, ([see this page](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2011/sep/27/behind-the-mask/?page=all)) is stated:

> Mr. Mendez’s greatest technical achievement may have been the creation
>   of an effective quick-disguise system — the Mendezes call it “Dagger”
>   — the details of which remain classified.
>
> “The difference between what Hollywood does in ‘Mission: Impossible’
>   is that it takes them five hours of makeup,” Mr. Mendez said. “We can
>   do it in five minutes without fail and with no makeup guy standing
>   there.”

Questions about creation of such masks:

- really exists  technology which can be used to produce such **really lifelike and realistic** masks?
- it is "machine based" technology?

Question about "scanning":

- I know I can make a plaster cast of the face. It is possible to make such a mask for example from photo or 3d scan?

So, I know here already exists technology what allows creation of latex or silicone masks, with a some degree of realism. Mostly based on face plaster cast = routinely used in movies.

The question is mainly about the existence of "sci-fi like" technology of creation of such masks - e.g. from photography or soo and with easy technology, like 3d printing and 3d modeling from photos...

*Ps: if someone knows better tags for this question, please edit...*

Comment: mythbusters did this once, they ruled that they exist and realistic enough but that close acquaintances will notice the difference

Comment: does anybody claim this can be done seriously?

Comment: @Sklivvz reworded and added a link and a citation - probably - it can be done seriously - or not?

Comment: The reference to "Dagger" is not a notable claim of a mask that resembles someone elses face. It is just that they had a disguise. It makes the question quite confused. Please give an example of someone claiming to be able to pass as someone else.